# LINQ to SQL (VB.net) : Join two tables and get only rows which have a maximum date on specific column

Tags: vb.net, join, linq-to-sql, max

This is my first time asking for help in this forum.
In the past, I was very fortunate to find the answer or work other people's responses to solve my problems. 
So, here is my question:

I have two tables.

A table called "Customers" with following columns:

- CustomerID (primary Key)
- CustomerName
- CustomerSurname

and a table called "Orders" with the following columns:

- OrderID (Primary Key)
- CustomerID (Foreign Key)
- DateOrderReceived
- OrderStatus
- DateOrderCompleted

One customer can have many orders(one to many). I need to create a new table using LINQ in VB.net that would include a combination of Customers with their latest order. Therefore, regardless of how many orders each customer may have placed, in my table I will only see one record for the combination CustomerX-LatestOrder. We can find the latest order by filtering on Column "DateOrderReceived"

Here is what I have done already:

```
  Dim query1 = From o In db.Orders, c In db.Customers Where c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID Group o By o.CustomerID Into g = Group Select CustomerID, MaxDate = g.Max(Function(o) o.DateOrderReceived)
```

The above code seems to select maximum Date correctly but my problem is that it only includes two columns: CustomerID and MaxDate. I cannot find any way to add all the rest columns and get a new joined table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After the 'select' keyword, define the columns you want to get

Comment: Thanks for your response. I 've tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Probably it has to do with the group keyword

Comment: Any help? Was my description not enough detailed?